# page doesn't match screen width (twitter bootsrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't manage to have my webpage fit the exact width of my screen, using bootstrap row fluid grid system.
Right now, I see a horizontal scrollbar that appears, but I thought it should fit the width of my screen!
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
@gridColumns: 24;
@fluidGridColumnWidth: 3.2%;
@fluidGridGutterWidth: 1.0086956%;

<body>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div id='leftbar' class='span3'>
        </div>
        <div id='content-wrapper' class='span17'>
            <div class='row-fluid'>
                <div id='header' class='span24'>
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div class='span8 header'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='span8 header'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='span8 header'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='flash-message' class='span24 center'>
                </div>
                <div id = 'content' class='span24'>
                   <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <div id = 'content-left' class='span10 center'>
                        </div>
                        <div id = 'content-right' class='span14 center'>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='rightbar' class='span4'>
        </div>
        <div id = 'footer' class='span24'>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried containing your code in the "container" class? From [Bootstrap's docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts): .

And also, at least in your sample code, your rows do not match up to the correct number of spans. The top most row has the following spans: 3 + 17 + 4 + 24 (the footer) = 48. The same problem occurs again in the inner rows.

To fix it,  just declare a new row for every set of 24 (or less) spans.

Comment: I followed your recommandations, added a container-fluid class container and declared a new row-fluid for every set of 24 spans. I don't have the scrollbar anymore and the behaviour of my elements makes more sense, but I have room on the left and right of the screen. Does the container-fluid class add some padding on the left and right? Ideally, I would like my right bar to stick to the extreme right of the screen, is it possible?

Comment: @Marronsuisse To do that, I think you might have to customize the CSS of the container-fluid class. Alternately, you could declare background colours for the body such that they match your left and right elements or then try without the container-fluid element entirely? However, if your original question was solved, then please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I removed the padding-right and padding-left off the container-fluid class in layouts.less. There's less space on the right but still something like a few pixels, I can't find what is causing it. I have images on the right of the screen so using a background color won't work.

Comment: @Marronsuisse What if you used Firebug (or equivalent) to inspect the difference between the applied CSS of the nav container (which goes all the way to the edges) and the container-fluid?

Comment: I am using Firebug to try to find out what's happening. The space at the right of the screen belongs to a 'row-fluid'. Problem is I haven't found a container that goes all way to the edges. What's the nav container? I only read of the class 'container' and 'container-fluid'.